# Hover effect over an image in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-server

I would like to add a kind of hover effect over an image. My source code in JavaScript looks like the following:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("color");
  function color(){
var $th = $("div[Name='Ampelberechnung']").parent();
var $index = $th.index();
$th.parent().parent().children(".ms-itmhover").each(function(index,elem){
var $div= $($(this).children("td").get($index));
var text= $div.text();
if(text=="OK"){
$div.html('<img src="#image">')
}
if(text=="notOK"){
$div.css("style","none");
$div.html('<img src="#image">');
    }
if(text=="critical"){
$div.css("style","none");
$div.html('<img src="#image">');
    }
    })}
```

Where and how I have to add the code?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve, better you demonstrate using some screen shots and include HTML code if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

You can just include the script into the parameter settings when you are building the area where you are including the image.  It might be easier to structure your code by removing any mention of hovering, just including the meat of the code:

```
if(text=="OK"){
$div.html('<img src="#image">')
}
if(text=="notOK"){
$div.css("style","none");
$div.html('<img src="#image">');
    }
if(text=="critical"){
$div.css("style","none");
$div.html('<img src="#image">');
```

You can define, in HTML, to execute a script when the mouse is over the object.  Something like

```
<div ... onmouseover="your script">
```

It might make things easier for you.

Comment: Hello and thank you, but I need to implemente this in javascript. I still not know where I can start.

Comment: I mean, the way to add javascript to a webpage is to include the function call in the xml or html code, so if you have access to that, aren't you able to add the onmouseover part?  You need to reference your script in the actual declaration of the area where your image will be.

Comment: I suppose if you want, you can run the script on Microsoft Powershell, as long as you are running it on the server.  Though I have only ever used scripting in Powerhsell to make changes, so it only needed to be run once.  I don't know if it would work when you constantly need to run the script.  Since it should be handled client side, you need to include it in the appropriate webpart.  To do this, you need to make changes to the HTML or XML code.  And if you can do this, you can use the onmouseover=script way.